# SVG artwork clipped on right edge

Tags: css, html, svg

I am fairly new to SVG, and the part that always confuses me is the size of the SVG and the clipping at the edges.  I have an SVG square in the below checkbox art I was trying to add a dropshadow to:

[image]

Turned out the code to do this is simple; but the right edge is clipped off.  I tried various combinations of widths and such, no luck.  What am I missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50">
  <defs>
      <filter id="blurFilter" y="-5" height="40">
        <feOffset in="SourceAlpha" dx="3" dy="3" result="offset2" />
        <feGaussianBlur in="offset2" result="blurredRect" stdDeviation="2" y="-"/>

        <feMerge>
         <feMergeNode in="blurredRect" />
         <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
       </feMerge>
      </filter>
  </defs>

  <g width="30" height="30" stroke="#00B140" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" >
   <rect  x="2" y="2" height="20" width="20" style="stroke: #3E53A4; fill: none; stroke-width=2px;filter: url(#blurFilter);"  />
    <path id="check" d="M21.542 11.271l-9.063 8.458-3.021-3.021"/>
  </g>
  </svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set width on the filter:

```
<filter id="blurFilter" y="-5" height="40" width="40">
```

### [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maio/1ogau5u8/)

for an explanation you can look into [filter feOffset definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#feOffsetElement);

shortly the reason is this filter primitive offsets the input image relative to its current position **in the image space by the specified vector**.

---

[updated fiddle based on Holgerwill's comment](https://jsfiddle.net/maio/1ogau5u8/1/)

Comment: be carefull the width and height of filter subregions are set in fractions of the objectBoundingBox. Thus the filter region in the example above width extent 40 times the width of the filtered element. you can use much smaller values, like y="-1.5" width="3" height="3" using smaller regions greatly improves performance of filters. in general keep the filtered region as small as possible.

Comment: @HolgerWill is right using `width="2" height="2" ` is enough